# Tracking code that monitors visitor stays on other sites

Tags: php, javascript, cookies, cross-domain, tracking

I want people to sign up to my site and give them a unique javascript snippet that they have to put on their site.
I have 2 questions.

1) Let's say I use the code below to track visit duration on their websites. The track below tracks when a person visits the site and leaves it but how can I make sure they actually leave the site and not just visit another page on that site's domain (meaning the user is still on their site). Cookies?

```
var timeLog = {
        start: null,
        end: null,
        init: function(){
            this.start = new Date().getTime();
        },
        sendResults: function(){
            this.end = new Date().getTime();
            var jData = { "client": "some-access-string", "start": this.start, "end": this.end };

            var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
            client.open("POST", "http://yoursite.com/process_info.php");
            client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
            client.send(JSON.stringify(jData));
        }
    };

    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        timeLog.sendResults();
    };

    timeLog.init();
```

2) I haven't done cross site scripting so I am wondering if javascript snippet calls the process_info.php script, would I be able try to set a cookie and also get $_SERVER variables such  $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']. Will that work since the actual php script will be on a different domain?

Comment: This looks tricky and I doubt you get 100% working due to security issues. What do you do with people that suddenly close the browser or disable javascript? I don't think setting a cookie would work as most browsers can block 3rd party cookies without blocking "normal" cookies.

Comment: If they close the browser it's still onbeforeunload I think. If they disable javascript well then there is not much you can do about it. I am not sure of any other way to implement this feature.

Comment: I modified your code, and when I used navigator.sendBeacon to submit a request, I obtained a script that works like a charm on many popular browsers (chrome, firefox, edge, Midori, chromium, brave, epiphany, opera, qutebrowser, and maybe some other no tested).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is not cross browser; it would be better to use `Image` to perform tracking, just dump all tracking data in the URL itself.

The advantage is that you can give a `<noscript>` snippet that includes an invisible tracking pixel as well without much modifications. The distribution and initialization of the script itself can be done with a small snippet like [this](https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1008080) that will insert a `<script>` tag in the body and run it.

Also, don't use `.onbeforeunload()`, that stuff is nasty. It's better to determine site departure by using session properties, such as time in between requests; if you don't receive another request within X minutes, assume the user has left.

Setting cookies from your PHP script should work as expected, as long as the cookie domain corresponds with the URL of your script (i.e. no third party cookies).

Comment: Or if you still want to use `onbeforeunload()` you can use `script` instead of `Image`. `<script src="trackingsite.com/track.js?customer_id=xyz">` and generate your load for image on `onbeforeunload` in that script

Comment: @Buksy It's best to keep the client side as simple and clean as possible and implement all the "smart" stuff on the server side.

Comment: Yes, but if you use only server side, you dont have access to plenty of information. Google analytics is generating own `script` tag too for example.

Comment: @Buksy I didn't say that, but I've made it more clear in the answer now.

Comment: What do you mean by "Image"? So to track visitor duration and number of impressions on their page, I can just give them <img src="http://www.mydomain.com/myscript.php?unique_id=34343"> and then process everything in myscript.php ? Do I just give them a javascript snippet that links to my image? What if I need to know more precise page duration. 0-5 seconds, 5-10 seconds, 10-15 seconds, 15+ seconds ?

Comment: @CodeCrack You would give them a snippet with both `<script>` and `<noscript>` blocks; one contains JavaScript that uses `new Image().src = 'http://yourhost/whatever';` and the other just contains the image ... your code will return a 1x1 transparent gif or something. If you really think such granularity of 5sec intervals is important, nothing stops you from a `.setTimeout()` approach :)

Comment: Sounds good. I also need it to be clickable, when a user clicks on the image, it will take them to a site of my choice. How would I implement that.

Comment: @CodeCrack Ehm, well .. the tracking pixel would be kinda invisible :)

Comment: I need to display an image/link of my choice on their website, generate a unique link and track the clicks.

Comment: @CodeCrack Oh, well, then just add that to the snippet I guess?

Comment: When you say "Setting cookies from your PHP script should work as expected, as long as the cookie domain corresponds with the URL of your script (i.e. no third party cookies)." My php script would be on my site and another site would use my snippet. So that means it would have to be a 3rd party cookie? Should I be dropping it with javascript then?

Comment: The domain serving the image would set the cookie as well so there's no third party stuff going on.